# I can't distinguish roles with my implementation in DRF+Angular

Tags: python, django, angular, django-rest-framework

I've made an implementation of a login system using django as backend and angular as frontend.

In the backend the authentication is implemented via the view associated to auth/signup

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers

from shopping.views import listatodoseventos

from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token, refresh_jwt_token

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('events',listatodoseventos),
    path('auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('auth/signup/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('auth/refresh-token/', refresh_jwt_token) 
]
```

In the frontend is done by this method

```
  signup(username:string, email:string, password1:string, password2:string){
    //todo
    return this.http.post(
      this.apiRoot.concat('signup/'),
      {username, email, password1, password2}
    ).pipe(
      tap(response=>this.setSession(response)),
      shareReplay()
    );
  }

It generates me these tables related with users.
I want to associate each user with a role.
But I don't know how to do that cause I don't know how to create entries in auth_user_groups
```

[link to the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjZsW.png)

Answer (score 0):

What i did  to associate a user with a specific role was to create groups and  to send the user with the groups to my angular application.

There are two solution to your problem.

**First would be to create groups:**
Here is how i created a group and added a user to it.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group,

    
group, group_has_been_created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=PRODUCT_MANAGER_GROUP_NAME)
group.user_set.add(product_manager_user)
```

After having a group and a associated user you can create a response to the angular application.

**And another way would be to create profiles and link then to your user.**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="user_profile", verbose_name=_("user")
    )
```

Here is a good article, which i also used :D.
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Hope this helps.